# MS Access - Calculated field with null values

Tags: ms-access, null

I'm trying to create a field to a database where the value is based on the sum of 2 other fields in the database which contains null values. I am trying to add

```
NZ([Number1])+NZ([Number2])
```

to the Expression in "Field Properties" "General" but access won't save it. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Access does not allow `Nz()` to be used in a Calculated field then you can use this instead:

```
IIf(IsNull([Number1]),0,[Number1])+IIf(IsNull([Number2]),0,[Number2])
```

**Edit re: comment**

To return Null if both components are Null, try

```
IIf(IsNull([Number1]) And IsNull([Number2]),Null,IIf(IsNull([Number1]),0,[Number1])+IIf(IsNull([Number2]),0,[Number2]))
```

Comment: Many thanks Gord works perfectly. The only issue i now have is that if all values are null then the calculated field value is 0. Any idea how to have this NULL or blank?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these directions to add a calculated field to your table:

1. Open the table by double-clicking it in the Navigation Pane.
2. Scroll horizontally to the rightmost column in the table, and click the Click to Add column heading.
3. In the list that appears, click Calculated Field, and then click the data type that you want for the result.   Access displays the
   Expression Builder.
4. Begin typing the calculation that you want for this field, for example:   Nz([Number1]) + Nz([Number2])

   Note    It is not necessary to precede the expression with an equal
   sign (=).
5. Click OK.   Access adds the calculated field, and then highlights the field header so that you can type a field name.
6. Type a name for the calculated field, and then press ENTER.

Comment: hi ive done that but it wont calculate if field is null. That is why i have added the Nz function but access wont accept it.

Comment: Nz() has a default for zero (0), but did you try specifying the zero?  Nz([Number1], 0) + Nz([Number2], 0)